# Create password protected file in linux

Tags: linux, security, passwords

i need to make my file password protected , whenever i tries to open the file it should ask for a valid password...

i found one method.

vi -x file name

whenever i open the file it asks for password that's fine.when am entering wrong password it shows some encrypted data that too fine.

with that encrypted data assume that somebody saved some unnecessary data.

when opening the same file with correct password that file contains valid data entered by its author and encrypted data entered by some other person...

so anybody suggest a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work the way you describe. You can protect a Logical Volume (LV) with a password, though. So the closest solution I can advice you is creating (for example) a LUKS partition, which will be encrypted and protected by password, and put the file(s) there.

Each time you need to access the file, you'll have to mount the LUKS partition by entering the password and only then you can access the files on it.

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/)'s a very easy tutorial on how to configure LUKS.